# How to get more search engines in Chrome right click?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, search-engines

Right now, if I select something and do a right click, the only search option I see is

> Search Google for 'whatever I
>   selected'

For example:

[image]

**How do I add more search engines to this list?**

Comment: Checkout Vivaldi - right click gives you 'Search with' and all your SEs are displayed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't add additional search engines, but you can change which search engine it uses. [Setting the default search](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95653) to Yahoo would then allow you to search Yahoo for the selected text. I think being able to add additional search engines to this list would be a great idea though, so I have added it as a [feature request.](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43680)

The only alternatives would be to use a bookmarklet like the one created for [Wikipedia](http://math-www.uni-paderborn.de/~axel/bookmarklet.html) or to use a [Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/), however both of these options would require clicking on a link or button instead of right clicking on the text.

Comment: I need to add. Most of the times I am using Google, but sometimes I need some others. Are you sure it is not possible?

Comment: As far as I know without changing the source code and recompiling the application it is not possible. I think it is a great idea though, and have added it as a feature request: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43680

You can star the issue to track the progress of the request.

Answer (score 17):

I am using this extension:
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ocpcmghnefmdhljkoiapafejjohldoga

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: It's worth noting that there are several extensions with this name (Context Menu Search). The one linked works just fine and allows you to easily drag and drop items to sort a list of search engines manually.

Comment: To add more than 5 engines, click Add search engines. Unfortunately, it doesn't synchronize settings with your google account. So you should export/import them manually if needed.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this issue and didn't like any of the extensions I found so I [built one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aagminaekdpcfimcbhknlgjmpnnnmooo?hl=en-US) :D
Please, do try it out and let me know what you think of it.

Answer (score 1):

[Context Menu Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/context-menu-search/ocpcmghnefmdhljkoiapafejjohldoga?hl=en) Google Chrome Extension would allow you to have any website as search engine. A detailed how to can be found at - [Customize Google Chrome Context Menu](http://www.techmyview.com/post/2014/01/31/Customize-Context-Menu-Search-in-Chrome-to-search-in-any-Website).